# What type of jQuery selector to use?

Tags: jquery

My question is simple. I have a HTML table for example with the following contents:

```
<table>
   <tr class="table-header">
      <td>first</td>
      <td>second</td>
      <td>third</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Which is the most effective way to select the `<td>` elements? Performance is the most important thing for me.

Should I just use `$("table-header td")` or rather add a `class="table-header-cell"` to every `<td>` and address them as `$('table-header-cell')`

You can abstract the example. This is a very simple situation but what about deeply nested HTML elements? Is it worth to add deep nested elements own class or just "grab" some high level element (closest one with a unique identifier [like: name, id or class] to our target ) and write a long "relative" selector?

Comment: Depending what you want to select. If you want to select single element than select with element name or give an id, but if you want to select multiple element then use class selector.

Comment: It depends on your DOM structure and your requirement you can use any selector that jquery supports..as performance i don't think it really helps..

Comment: i think adding class or id is better than long selector becuase it is more direct

Comment: `Performance is the most important thing for me` So don't use jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

It would be alot easier doing it with adding class to each element and it's more direct, but if you'd prefer to not add class to each element then use the way of setting a `class` or `id` to the table and doing this way `$(".table-header td")`.

Performance wise there is no difference, it really doesn't matter.

```js
$(".table-header td").css({color: "red"});
```

```css
.table-cell
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
   <tr class="table-header">
      <td>first</td>
      <td>second</td>
      <td>third</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="table-cell">first</td>
      <td class="table-cell">second</td>
      <td class="table-cell">third</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID selection is fastest, followed closely by class selectors. As there are multiples a class selector will be the fastest option, however there is a compromise solution.

As Sizzle evaluates selectors from *right-to-left*, long selectors are actually the slowest option. You can use an initial selector to target the ancestor using the class (very fast), then `find` the `TD`s from there (reasonably fast as it targets only that branch of the DOM):

i.e.

```
$(".table-header").find("td")
```

or a scoped selector

```
$("td", ".table-header")
```

In any case, make sure you don't suffer from *premature optimisation*. Profiling tools will help, as will researching the relative speed of various selection methods. As `@A. Wolff` points out, jQuery is not the fastest solution, compared with raw browser methods, so whatever you do is a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to imagine how you would perform the search.  The selector could be potentially searching for several elements, meaning even if there is only one element to find, you're searching the entire DOM just the same.  So logically, searching for something by its id would almost certainly be faster since rather than perform a search, jQuery simply calls document.getElementById.  Done.

The browser notes the position of each element with an id so that you're not so much finding an element by its id so much as recalling it from a cache for performance.  So rule #1:  use *ids* whenever possible.

Suppose you're looking for several children under an id.  It can't simply call document.getElementById like above.  True, but jQuery optimizes such searches.  The parent element is retrieved like above, and then a search is done within the DOM of that element.  Meaning, even searches of children under ids is optimized.  So rule #2:  use *ids* whenever possible.

Specific paths should be favored over more generic paths.  This is because the subset of possible elements to search diminishes if you provide more information.  So in other words $('table tbody tr td') is better than $('table td').  You would not expect to find a td in the thead, but the search is performed in the thead regardless.  So rule #3:  prefer more specific paths.

Specific paths helps, but only if you combine it with rule #4 to use > to ensure that the element is a direct child of the parent.  In other words $('table > tbody > tr > td') beats $('table tbody tr td').  Without this, all children elements must be searched.  This may not make much difference for small tables, but it has a direct impact on performance with larger tables.  So rule #4:  use > to select direct children of parent whenever possible.

Lastly, is it more efficient to search for all children by a class or without?  There is a small performance improvement if you're say, searching for all tds under a table with a given class rather than all tds with a given class.  This is mostly due to the fact that in one case you're collecting all td tags under an element with the found class and in the other, you're checking each and every td tag for that class.  This difference is more pronounced if there are a lot of children elements, but I don't think the difference is so significant unless you're genuinely dealing with thousands of elements.  So rule #3:  unless you need to distinguish each child element by class, prefer to select the children via the parent (table.myclass td rather than table td.myclass).

TL;DR;

In summary:

- use *ids* whenever possible.
- prefer more specific paths.
- use > to select direct children of parent whenever possible.
- unless you need to distinguish each child element by class, prefer to select the children via the parent (table.myclass td rather than table td.myclass).

Comment: Q: As selectors are parsed *right to left*, won't using `>` and "select the child via the parent" both slow down selection (compared to using separate top-down selection operations operations like `$(".table-header").find("td")`)? basically any complex selector is going to be slower than single selectors chained.

Comment: Why would searching for each component individually be more efficient than asking the browser to do it for you?  Maybe I'm missing something, but performing many chained searches using find would be a bit like performing an SQL query and then another for each child rather than let the database do that for you.  I fail to see how that could be *more* efficient in the larger scheme of things.

Comment: It is more efficient as each subsequent `find` one will only target *the descendants in that branch*. Only the initial `class` search is actually efficient. If you use a long jQuery selector it runs the last element and finds all matches, then filters that against the second last element and so on. It all comes down to how Sizzle is implemented and apparently the latest version has some rather fast shortcuts which may make current efficiency information obsolete.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye So why would Sizzle optimize class searching and not search only descendents in a given branch?  To check for the existence of a child element without a parent that fits the selector seems the most relevant type of optimization one can perform.

Comment: I think you will find class searching is only optimised if it is the only, or last, expression present in a selector. Sizzle was initially written in a way that made Sizzle *easy to write*. i.e. a right to left parser that processes one token/expression at a time. Any optimisations will be, or were, added afterwards. As Sizzle has been dramatically changed *just recently* the only thing I can suggest is use JSPerf to test various selectors (if you can't find existing ones) and make no assumptions about optimisations based on what seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends of what you want to do, but your code becomes more clear if you navigate through the elements using their own tag names, like you did.

The selector using the class of the row "**table-header**" and selecting all "**td**" inside

```
$(".table-header td");
```

The selector using the name of the table tag and selecting all "**td**" inside

```
$("table tr td");
```

Just to help you imporve your code, you can use "**th**", it's specific to the table header

```
<table>
   <th>
      <td>First Header</td>
      <td>Second Header</td>
      <td>Third Header</td>
   </th>
   <tr>
      <td>First Element</td>
      <td>Second Element</td>
      <td>Thrid Element</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

... so you can use more specific tags selectors

```
$("table th");
$("table th td");
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, it's usually more performant to avoid child selectors like `$('.table td')` because if the browser doesn't support `document.querySelectorAll` then this requires additional parsing and then DOM navigation to return the selected elements. For the equivalent selector, it's better to use `$('.table').find('td')`.

But for your example, it would be most performant to have a class on every `<td>` element that you want to select and use a single class name selector, which will internally use a call to the native function `document.getElementsByClassName` which is less work and therefore much faster.

There's documentation on selector performance here: http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/